# What permission I need to post score on facebook SDK Unity

Tags: c#, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to post my game score on facebook with facebook SDK on Unity, but when I try to post the unity throw this message:

403 Forbidden
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
c__AnonStoreyB:<>m__8(FBResult) (at Assets/FL Plugin Scripts/FacebookManager.cs:307)
Facebook.c__Iterator0:MoveNext()

When I log in I use this permissions:

B.Login("email,publish_actions,public_profile,publish_stream,read_stream,export_stream", LoginCallback);

Thanks!

Comment: And which permissions have the user granted? Use /me/permissions to check. You need publish_actions. publish_stream and export_stream doesn't exists. read_stream you will not be approved for.

Comment: I use this permissions email,publish_actions,public_profile

Comment: And I have this permissions {"data":[{"permission":"installed","status":"granted"},{"permission":"public_profile","status":"granted"},{"permission":"user_friends","status":"granted"}]}

Comment: Then you haven't asked for publish_actions

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

Well, Facebook only give the publish_actions permissions if you are the development for your app.

So, if you want to try your app, you need to log in your smartphone with your facebook account set has developer.

And that's it.

If you want to ask the public_actions with other users, you need to do this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review